# Как сделать добавление товара в корзину?

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

Мне нужно реализовать добавление определенного товара в корзину(например с id 32007) при нажатии на кнопку(1-С Битрикс)

```
<a class="element-card__info-button" href="<?= SITE_DIR ?>personal/cart/" onclick="">ЗАКАЗАТЬ РАСЧЁТ</a>
```